# Keeping track of results when executing a Java stream?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a basic stream where I am iterating through objects in a stream and I want to persist the return value into a list so I can use it once the stream is done. Each time I call the function it returns an integer.

Is this one of those scenarios where I should use a for-loop, or can I still use a stream? Each time `doSomeFunctionThatReturnsAnInt` is called, I want to store the return value or keep appending the return to a list.

```
myCoolCollectionObject
        .getCoolList()
        .stream()
        .forEach(this::doSomeFunctionThatReturnsAnInt);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to map the elements of the stream to an int (with the function you have) and collect it to a list using [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
List<Integer> result = myCoolCollectionObject
                         .getCoolList()
                         .stream()
                         .map(this::doSomeFunctionThatReturnsAnInt)
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or `int[] result = … .mapToInt(this::doSomeFunctionThatReturnsAnInt).toArray();`

Comment: @Holger Sure. Indeed :)